# Cumulatively add values to a dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have a list of 2 different dictionaries which I update in a function, however I want to run this in a for loop where for loop two I want to iteratively add to these 2 dictionaries that I already have.

```
def dictionaries_test(items):
    a = dict()
    for column in items:
            #print("group:",column)
            [s, i] = column
            combined = '%s,%s' % (s, i)
            if combined in a:
                a[combined] += 1
            else:
                a[combined] = 1
    return a
```

```
def isolation_forest(df, n_trees=2, subspace=256):
    X = df.values
    forest = []
    n = subspace
    node_paths = []
    c = []
    
    max_depth = np.ceil(np.log(subspace))

    for i in range(n_trees):
        
        dataFrame = df.sample(subspace)
        
        tree = isolation_tree(dataFrame, max_depth=max_depth)
        
        # Save tree to forest
        forest.append(tree)  
           
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        instance = df.iloc[[i]]
        paths = []
        d = {}
        j = 0
        node_paths = []
        
    for tree in forest: 
        j = j+1
    
        paths.append(pathLength(instance,tree))
        node_paths.append(paths[j-1][1]) 
   
        d.append(dictionaries_test(node_paths))
        node_paths.clear()

    c.append(d)
    print("c:",c)
```

The problem is that I want to iteratively append new values to c in the already existing 2 dictionaries, I know this is the wrong structure but I don't know how to solve it. Currently c updates and add 2 new dictionaries for each loop. I want to add the keys to the 2 dictionaries, not append 2 more.

```
c: [[{'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,19.818156222977095': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,5.363540682822778': 1,
 'Ask_Avg_Volume,9.323600245263918': 1},
{'Ask_Avg_Volume,197.50444935762542': 1,
 'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,42.21451340936669': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,3.3998163712677645': 1}]]

Second iteration:

c: [{'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,335.1846225162': 1,'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,40.96866540084905': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,13.323205588601743': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,659.3733901302467': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,4.417019295299902': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,54.943278300874425': 1},
{'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,335.1846225162': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,40.96866540084905': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,13.323205588601743': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,659.3733901302467': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,4.417019295299902': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,54.943278300874425': 1},
{'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,335.1846225162': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,40.96866540084905': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,13.323205588601743': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,659.3733901302467': 1,
'Ask_Avg_Volume,4.417019295299902': 1,
'Avg_Order_Insert_Size,4.935231863487447': 1}]
```

So in the variable c I want to add the next loop into the specific dictionaries, and not append them to create 2 more.

Comment: Is that normal that I don't see the declarations of the `i` and `j` iteration variables that you use in both loops ?

Comment: I am sorry, added the whole function

Comment: Maybe it's an identation problem, but the declarations `paths = [] ; d = {} ;  j = 0 ; node_paths = []` inside the loop doesn't seems useful. It doesn't solve your problem but for the moment the code is not easy to read :).

Comment: I know it might be hard to read, some code is just there momentarily to get it to work decently. However I need something that works as append but instead of adding to a list I need it to add to the already existing dictionaries

Comment: Ok, then if there is no indentation error from you, you could start by get the declarations I mentionned above out of the loop. I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do but for now it's rather unclear..

Comment: Also the `instance` variable you create for each iteration on the `df.shape[0]` is unused in the loop.

Comment: Or maybe each loop is nested inside the previous one. That could make sense (so there is an indentation problem). But in this state I really don't understand anything to that code :/;

Comment: It is not really intuitive because it is using plenty of external functions to run, however j=0 is declared for example to reset itself for each node (I run for each node, then I traverse the node for 2 trees). My guess would be that one might be able to tell a solution by watching the output only, I need a clue how to add to these 2 dictionaries, and not appending more dictionaries.

Comment: but what about the instance variable ? the `df.iloc[[i]]`values will all be unsued except for the last iteration, it can't be normal ?

Comment: It is used for the external function pathLength (choosing a row i from a DataFrame) which basically gets me the output before I convert it to a dictionary

Comment: No it's not used, only last value for last `i` is used. Sorry if the code doesn't make sense I really don't see how to help make it work.

Comment: No problem, it works I don't know what you saw but it uses i as it should, choosing different rows (instances).